# operations in double for loop doesn't work R

Tags: r, for-loop

The problem: AF is not cumulutaing. And its something wrong with the addressing to matrix elements and with the comparison...

My data

```
VF <- matrix(c(40, 70, 80, 35, 
             90, 66, 15, 46, 
             50, 52, 60, 80,
             30, 73, 30, 40,
             80, 70, 76, 69), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)

VA <- matrix(c(40, 25, 67, 43, 
               5, 26, 80, 43, 
               45, 35, 30, 10,
               63, 13, 60, 45,
               10, 19, 11, 22), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)

UV <- c(1, 0, 0, 1)
```

I try to call my function

```
f <- function(VF, VA, UV) {
  vote_for <- VF
  vote_against <- VA
  user_vote <- UV
  am_law <- ncol(vote_for)
  am_fr <- nrow(vote_for)
  AF <- 0
  AFP_vec <- c(0)
  for (i in 1:am_fr) {
    AF <- 0
    for (j in 1:am_law) {
      if (user_vote[j] == 1) { 
        AF <- AF + vote_for[i][j]
      } else { 
        AF <- AF + vote_against[i][j] 
      }
    }
    AFP <- AF / am_law
    append(AFP_vec, AFP) 
  } 
  return(AFP_vec) 
}
```

The result of calling

```
 f(VF, VA, UV)
```

is

```
[1] 40 [1] NA [1] NA [1] NA [1] 90 [1] NA [1] NA [1] NA [1] 50
[1] NA [1] NA [1] NA [1] 30 [1] NA [1] NA [1] NA [1] 80 [1] NA [1] NA [1] NA [1] 0
```

but I wish it would be only 5 values in my AFP_vec.

Please, help me. I'm beginner. And I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Hey, Please could you clarify what you are expecting the output to look like.

Comment: Depending on values in UV, i choose elements from matrix vote_for or vote_against and cumulates them. (i expect AF is my cumulative variable). Then i calculate mean in one set of elements (passing one step in "for (i in 1:am_fr)" - loop ) - AFP and push into vector AFP_vec.
According to my data, AFP_vec must give me 5 values

Comment: Ok my current understanding is the output should be a vector that is the same length as the number of rows as VF & VA where the value of the element is the mean of the rows in VF & VA where you take VF if UV =1  and VA if UV = 0 ?

Comment: Yeah.
For the first passing "for (i in 1:am_fr)" - loop :
AF=40+25+67+35=167; AFP=41.75 ; first el of AFP_vec is 41.75.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not entirely sure of what your after but I think this might be along the right lines. Am happy to explain the code if required.

```
VF <-  matrix(
   c(40 ,  70 ,  80   ,35,
   90 ,  66  , 15 ,  46,
   50 ,  52  , 60  , 80,
   30 ,  73  , 30 ,  40,
   80 ,  70 ,  76  , 69) , nrow = 5 , byrow = T
 )

VA <-  matrix(
  c(40,   25,   67 ,  43,
    5,   26 ,  80 ,  43,
   45 ,  35 ,  30  , 10 ,   
   63 ,  13,   60  , 45,
   10  , 19 ,  11,   22 ), nrow = 5 , byrow = T
)

UV <- c( 1, 0, 0, 1)


mat <-  (t(VF) * UV )  +   (t(VA) * ! UV )
apply( mat , 2 , mean)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! looks much better :) dont need explaination of your code, google helped me. not so much as you, of course)) 
but could you be so kind to explain why my function doesn't work? it would be a good experience. i want know not only the right decision, but my mistakes too.

Comment: oh, Chirayu Chamoli has already answered . so i can see what was wrong. thank you!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer any chance you could mark as answered ? @Chet

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code to correct the errors in it. This should work now. But the mentioned solution is much better.

```
fun<-function(VF,VA,UV)
{
    vote_for<-VF
    vote_against<-VA
    user_vote<-UV
    am_law<-ncol(vote_for)
    am_fr<-nrow(vote_for)
    AF<-0
    AFP_vec<-list()
    for (i in 1:am_fr)
    {
        AF<-0
        for (j in 1:am_law)
        {

            if (user_vote[j] == 1){ AF=AF+vote_for[i,j]}
            else { AF=AF+vote_against[i,j] }

        }

        AFP<-AF / am_law
        AFP_vec[i]=AFP
    } 
    return(AFP_vec) }


res=fun(VF,VA,UV)
```